# The right approach to do Elasticsearch upgrades via terraform

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to discuss what are the best practices/approaches engineers do while upgrading `elasticsearch` clusters. I believe this post may serve as a good example of strategies and steps to perform, guaranteeing no data loss, minimum downtime, scalability and availability of the `elasticsearch` services.

To start the initiative, we can break the upgrade into two subsections:

1) Performing upgrade on `master nodes`:

Since master nodes do not contain any data and are responsible for controlling the cluster I believe we can safely do terraform apply to add all the upgraded master node VMs and then remove the old ones.

2) Performing upgrade on `data nodes`:

As many people already know, there is certain limitation on the ability to update data nodes. We cannot afford to completely deallocate the VM and replace it with another. A good practice in my opinion is to:

a) Stop the index allocation to the old VM

b) Then performing `terraform apply` to create the new upgraded version of the data node VM(and manually modifying the `terraform state` in order the old VM not to be destroyed)

c) Allowing traffic(index creation) to the new VM and using the `elasticsearch` APIs to transfer the data from the old to the new VM

d) Manually changing the `terraform state` allowing it to delete the old VM.

These are just idealistic steps, I would like to see your opinion and strategies to perform safe **elasticsearch** upgrades via **Terraform**.

Answer (score 1):

The reference manual has guidelines regarding [removing master-eligible nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-adding-removing-nodes.html#modules-discovery-removing-nodes) that you must respect in versions 7 and later. It's much trickier to get this right in earlier versions because of the `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` setting.

Your strategy for data nodes sounds slow and expensive given that you might be moving many terabytes of data around for each node. It's normally better to restart/upgrade larger data nodes "in place", detaching and reattaching the underlying storage if needed.